# How may Sphider be modified to display an image in search results, without knowing the name of the image

Tags: php, html, image, search

Using the code below with the Sphider search engine, Sphider will display an image in search results - if the html page and jpg share the same name (i.e) page14.html, and page14.jpg.

1) Without knowing the name of the image, how could the code be modified so that the first of 2-3 jpg's is displayed from the html page returned in search results ?

```
<?PHP
$url_path = "http://www.webpage.com/"; // The url to indexed pages.
$url_ext = ".html";                    // The file ext. of indexed pages.
$image_path = "../";                   // Path to image folder.
$image_ext = ".jpg";                   // The file extension of images.
$image = str_replace("$url_path", "$image_path", $url);
$image = str_replace("$url_ext", "$image_ext", $image);
    if (file_exists($image)) { // Do nothing
} else { $image = $image_path . "ICS" . $image_ext; } ?>
<img src="<?PHP print $image ?>" align="left" style="margin-right:10px;" />
```

Or,

2) How would I modify the above php code to display the images below in search results - without renaming all the images ?

I have many gallery pages with hundreds of the following html image links;

```
<a href="page_02.html"><img SRC="chair_0.jpg"></a>
<a href="page_03.html"><img SRC="table_0.jpg"></a>
<a href="page_04.html"><img SRC="bed_0.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all our webpage images have the same ID as the end of each page. 
Following is an example of how our pages look like: www.mywebsite.com/category/sub-category/etc/details.php?category=6&subcategory=s&sc=180&productid=98

The pictures are located in another path, and share the same last digits (i.e 98) as web page.
Following is an example of picture folder: www.mywebsite.com/admin/picures/

In addition, all pictures have an extra "p" at the front and "_full" at end of the digits, as following example "p98_full.jpg", p109_full.jpg" or "p3_full.jpg".

Following method worked for me. You will need to past this on sphider/templates/standard/search_results.html line # 76, modify it a bit to match your setting and see if it works... (You do not need to add a url link to your site to this code, this should work as is)

```html
  <?PHP

      $url_ext = ".php";                                      // The file extension of indexed pages.
      $image_path = "../admin/pictures/";                           // Path to image folder.
     $pic_name = "p";            // Alphabet before image, if any.
      $page_end = Substr ($url2, strrpos($url2, "=")+1);  // Isolate digits or alphabets starting from end of page.
      $image_ext = "_full.jpg";                                    // The file extension of images.
     $image = $image_path . "$pic_name$page_end" . $image_ext;  // Select isolated digits or alphabes.
    
      if (file_exists($image)) { // Do nothing
   } else { $image = $image_path . "ICS" . $image_ext; } ?>
      <img src="<?PHP print $image ?>" alt="" align="left" style="margin-right:10px; border:0;" />
```